# SimpleInjector- I couldn't able to get instance

Tags: c#-4.0, dependency-injection, simple-injector

I registered few types(interface and its concrete type) in the container using batch addition from a folder(below is the code). when I try to retrieve the instance I couldn't able to get the instance.

```
    var pluginDLLs = new DirectoryInfo(pluginDirectory).GetFiles()
    .Where(file => file.Extension.ToLower() == ".dll")
    .ToList();

var pluginAssembliesList = 
    pluginDLLs.Select(dll => Assembly.LoadFrom(dll.FullName)).ToList();

var pluginAssemblies = pluginAssembliesList
    .Where(pluginAssembly => pluginAssembly.FullName.StartsWith("QS."))
    .ToList();

pluginAssembliesTypes = 
    pluginAssemblies.SelectMany(a => a.GetExportedTypes()).ToList();

//Identify commands based on ICommand. Code that identifies all command including ICommandGetTestResultsRun
var icommandType = pluginAssembliesTypes
    .First(type => type.IsInterface && type.Name.Equals("ICommand"));

var commands = (
    from type in pluginAssembliesTypes
    where !type.IsInterface
    where icommandType.IsAssignableFrom(type) 
    where type.GetInterfaces().Any(t => type.GetConstructor(new Type[] { t }) != null)
    select new
    { 
        Service = type.GetInterfaces()
            .First(t => type.GetConstructor(new Type[] { t }) != null), 
        Implementation = type 
    }).ToList();
commands.ForEach(reg => 
    container.Register(reg.Service, reg.Implementation, Lifestyle.Transient));

var test = container.GetInstance(typeof (ICommandGetTestResultRuns));
```

I am attaching the screenshot of Simple Injector source code where I think it is failing.  Could you somebody figure out what I am not doing right.

Here is the ICommandGetTestResultRuns Implementation.

```
namespace QS.Rand.BusinessLogic.Commands
{
public interface ICommand
{
}
}

namespace QS.Rand.BusinessLogic.Commands.TestResults
{
public interface ICommandGetTestResultRuns : ICommand
{
    IntFilter IdTestRequestFilter { get; set; }
    IntFilter IdSampleFilter { get; set; }
    IntFilter IdBatchFilter { get; set; }
    IntFilter IdFilter { get; set; }
}
}

namespace QS.Rand.BusinessLogic.Commands
{
public class CommandGetTestResultRuns : Command<IEnumerable<ITestResultRun>>, ICommandGetTestResultRuns
{
    protected static readonly log4net.ILog logger = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(CommandGetTestResultRuns));
    #region ICommandGetTestRuns implementation
    public IntFilter IdTestRequestFilter { get; set; }
    public IntFilter IdSampleFilter { get; set; }
    public IntFilter IdBatchFilter { get; set; }
    public IntFilter IdFilter { get; set; } 
    #endregion

    protected DA.ITestRunRepository TestRunRepository { get; set; }

    public CommandGetTestResultRuns() { }

    public CommandGetTestResultRuns(ICommandGetTestResultRuns cmd)
    {
        IdTestRequestFilter = cmd.IdTestRequestFilter;
        IdFilter = cmd.IdFilter;
        IdSampleFilter = cmd.IdSampleFilter;
        IdBatchFilter = cmd.IdBatchFilter;
    }

    public override IResult<IEnumerable<ITestResultRun>> Execute()
    {
        var result = new Result<IEnumerable<ITestResultRun>>();
        var filter = new DaTestRunFilter();
        try
        {
            var daRuns = TestRunRepository.GetTestRuns(filter, new List<Tuple<string, DA.OrderDirection>>());
            var runs = new List<ITestResultRun>();
            result.Value = runs;
            result.IsOK = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            result = new Result<IEnumerable<ITestResultRun>>() { IsOK = false, Message = new ResultMessage() { Level = MessageLevel.Error, Text = ex.Message }, Value = null };
            logger.Error(ToLogString(), ex);
        }
        return result;
    }

    private string ToLogString()
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.AppendFormat("Unable to load test request samples");
        return sb.ToString();
    }

}
```

}

[image]

Comment: Please explain what's going wrong. Please include the expected behavior and the experienced behavior. Include the exception details if such thing is thrown.

Comment: btw, do your command implementations implement a generic interface or are you implementing [this pattern](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=91)? And will the list of command assemblies changes are deployment, or are you just trying to decouple the presentation layer from the business layer?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply(Didn't have notification).  I injected the interface(as key) with its implementation. When I try to get the instance back SimpleInjector throwed an exception saying "{"No registration for type ICommandGetTestResultRuns could be found."}.

Comment: The only difference I see is that the Inteface(service) and its Implemenation are loaded from a directory(plugin directory). When I retrieve the dependency out of container I use the same interface which is from bin\Debug (type.Assembly.Module location is different from plugin directory) but that shouldn't matter. When I step into SimpleInjector source  I see that code to retrieve the dependency from the Dictionary fails (with interface as the key) which means the key(interface) in the dictionary and key(same interface) I am using to retrieve it doesn't match. I don't why it wouldn't match.

Comment: Yes I was using similar pattern as you mentioned in your blog. The list of commands can change in the deployment i.e. It is enough to replace a dll to change the implementation of a command/s.

Comment: So where exactly did you register `ICommandGetTestResultRuns`? I don't see a registration for that interface in your configuration.

Comment: **`commands.ForEach(reg => 
    container.Register(reg.Service, reg.Implementation, Lifestyle.Transient));`**  I highlighted the registration part from my code block posted above. I am using automatic registration.

Comment: Please update your question and add the `ICommandGetTestResultRuns` implementation that you expect to be registered.

Comment: Code to register(Automatic registration) is already there in the question(Inside the code). I am not only registering ICommandGetTestResultRun there are many command I am registering and I tried to get one command named 'ICommandGetTestResultRun'. It happens for every command I am trying to get from the SimpleInjector. I will also highlight the registration part in my question

Comment: I added the implementation of ICommandGetTestResultRuns in the question

Comment: If Simple Injector says: "No registration for type ICommandGetTestResultRuns could be found.", this simply means that you didn't register that interface you are requesting in that container instance. Check the `commands` list with registrations. That interface is most likely not in that list.

Comment: The interface is actually there in the registration. I have shown the interface presence in the container as well interface details in the screenshot. Loot at arrows pointing both interface details and container that contains the interface. Only thing I can do now is that I can create a small test project with the problem and upload it somewhere let me know if you like that.

Comment: My bet is that you are not resolving the same interface. There are two options here. Either there are 2 interfaces with the same name, or your projects reference to different versions of the assembly that contains that interface (making the runtime see two interfaces). The latter can usually be fixed by using the correct binding redirects in your config file.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply I have been pulled to other priority work. I tried referring the same dll from plugin directory but still no luck. I created sample demo project and here is the link to download the same. You can see for yourself. https://www.dropbox.com/sh/y7phubink9o48zj/AAAM6lWG2UmJxkt7oFPgRCmga?dl=0

Comment: I figured this out. Now I modified the code to verify the container(should have done it as first thing) SimpleInjector throwed an exception saying that type is directly or indirectly depending on itself. It is because of the way it is designed/architectured. Thanks for your comments though